# kernel_require.rb cannot load such file jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I'm very new to Jekyll and I am trying to run existing, correct project, so the problem I guess is in my system configuration. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. I succesfully installed jekyll with `sudo gem install jekyll` but when I run `jekyll s` the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
        4: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        3: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/exe/jekyll:11:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:50:in `require_from_bundler'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
```

Am I missing any package? 
`echo $PATH` results with `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Answer (score 0):

That is what helped:

```
gem install bundle
rm -rf _site
bundle update
jekyll s
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing Gemfile.lock did the trick for me.